# Fetching data from database

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have data in my datalogging table as shown below

```
Name       Shiftname      operatorname        Date       plantname       line       machine
Ashwini   Shift1(7-3)   Operator 1     2011-05-24      Plant 1  Line1       mc1
Deepika   Shift2(3-11)  Operator 2     2011-05-24      Plant 2      Line3      mc5
Pradeepa      Shift2(11-7)  Operator 3     2011-05-25      Plant 3  Line5      mc10
Deepika    Shift1(7-3)  Operator 1     2011-05-25      Plant 1  Line1      mc1
```

i want to reteive data based on plant i have written code like this but it not displaying data

i dont know what is the problem

can any1 help me on this

i have wriiten code like this

```
select machine,operatorname,line from datalogging1
where plantname='plant1' and date='2011/05/25'
```

i want my output has

```
machine     operatorname       line
mc1          operator1         line1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your plant name is "Plant 1", `plantname='plant1'` won't work!

Comment: No problem - definitely better to check and double-check rather than posting straight onto SO.